# Using SQLite in Windows 8 DESKTOP app

Tags: .net, wpf, sqlite, windows-8, desktop

Hi does anyone know how to configure Visual Studio 2012 Desktop to use SQLite in a desktop app?

I have been spending ages trying to work it - I got it working in Visual Studio 2012 Metro Apps but there is no Extensions in VS 2012 Desktop so it seems to be a bit different.

I have tried adding a reference to the SQLite3.dll but VS refuses to acknowledge it as a library.

I have been trying to use Tim Heurs instructions without success.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies - developing a WPF application in C#

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)?

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153407/WPF-and-SQLite-Database) an example WPF application on CodeProject that uses same SQLite library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should using this binaries, in order to use with .NET,

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki,

What version of .net in your project ? 4.0 or 4.5 ?